# Angular binding to inherited scope variables

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am learning angular and tried to implement dynamic binding on my test page. My goal was to implement input boxes, each one binded to one of dynamically obtained variable name.

If I will not declare results array in root scope - it will create results array for every repetition and under each box I will see it's own results content.

But if I DO decalre results in root scope,  and since I do not redeclare it - no shadowing must apply and I should bind each box to variable in root scope's array. But instead I see only root scope's array content under each box, and it does not change, while changing inputs.
Any help appreciated.

Here is my example:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="index.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="main" > <!--ng-init="results = [{'TEST': 1}]" -->

<div>
    <p>Name: <input type="text" ng-model="name"></p>
    <p ng-bind="name"></p>
    <input type="button" value="Clickme" ng-click="clickfnc()">
    <input type="button" value="Dump" ng-click="dump()">
    <input type="button" value="Pop" ng-click="remove()">
</div>

<div ng-repeat="x in params">
    <p>Name: <input type="text" ng-model="results[x.name]"></p>
    <p ng-bind="results[x.name]"></p>
    <p>{{x.name}}</p>
    <p>{{results}}</p>
    <p>{{params}}</p>
</div>

<hr>

<p ng-bind="results"></p>

<hr>

</body>
</html>
```

index.js:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('main', function ($scope)
{
    $scope.clickfnc = function ()
    {
        console.log('click');

        $scope.params = [
            {
                name: 'ACCOUNT'
            },
            {
                name: 'AMOUNT'
            }
        ];
    };

    $scope.dump = function ()
    {
        console.log($scope.results)
    };

    $scope.remove = function ()
    {
        $scope.params.pop();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly what is your goal, the reason you failed that your created `results` array, but you should create object.

Here: `<p>Name: <input type="text" ng-model="results[x.name]"></p>` 
 you assigning new properties to results, so it should be object. You can check this fiddle -  https://jsfiddle.net/kb5udcac/

Comment: Thank you! My mistake, will look better before asking next time.